# jqGrid: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid

At the moment, I'm trying to get a basic grid to simply show on the screen. Following the jqGrid wiki, I linked to/created scripts for the necessary files. There was on css file that was not present in the jqGrid zip that I downloaded, which was jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css. I had to find that separately and add it.
Currently, I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"   href="../Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4.7.1/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4.7.1/css/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css"/>

<script src="../jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4.7.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"</script>
<script src="../Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4.7.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h1").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: "loadform.php",
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: "GET",
            colNames: ["Name", "Social Security Number", "Date of Birth", "Income"],
            colModel: [
            {name: "name", width: 100},
            {name: "ssn", width: 100},
            {name: "dob", width: 100},
            {name: "income", width: 100}
            ],
            rowNum: 5,
            autoencode: true
       })
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <center><h1>Scrolling Data Form With jQuery</h1>
    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if the files I've included are invalid, or if they're not being reached, or if I haven't included all the necessary files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your script tag are not correct use it like,

```
<script src="../Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4.7.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4.7.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, try to change the order of your jqGrid load the `grid.locale-en.js` after `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`.

Also, verify that you have included the libraries(above 2 files + jquery) in script tab of firebug.

Also, in your code your are using [$.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) 2 times, you can remove any one from then below

```
// remove any 1 line, from the below
$(document).ready(function() { // ready function
  $(function(){ // ready shorthand
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even notice close the tags! That solved it. I'll change the things you suggested as well. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeD you should try to use a code editor for these changes. Even in your question you can see that the syntax highlight for the "bad" lines is not working correctly. These visual cues can be very useful in diagnosing these kind of problems